# Bootstrap 4, is-pending form validation state

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to do a form pending state while checking server api for field validity. Using Bootstrap 4 scss code, I modified this piece of code in `_form.scss` file :

[image]

Normally, now setting is-warning, should put the form input in a warning state where the border are in warning color, but it not working, is-valid and is-invalid are of course working correctly

I have checked that the css related to `is-warning` is correctly add in Firefox debugger console, i just don't know why `is-warning` don't apply the correct effect event if it present in css.

Comment: something is overwriting that, what does the actual css say on the element you want?

Comment: i inspected it, it is like if there was no css styles for the `.is-warning` class, its not bein overwritten

Comment: Try to add the class `was-validated` alongside the `is-warning` class.

Comment: done too, still not working, only showing in validated state( green )

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue here? We can't inspect code in a picture.

Comment: yes of course, but how can i upload the whole scss code in an online website, do jsfiddle support that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@include form-validation-state("warning", ...)` cannot work because of lines like this one: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.3/scss/mixins/_forms.scss#L55

```
.form-control,
  .custom-select {
    .was-validated &:#{$state},  // <====
    &.is-#{$state} {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

See `:#{$state}`? it will generate `:warning` which does not exist in CSS.
The CSS pseudo classes [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) and [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) do exist so they work.

When the browser encounters a CSS selector that he does not understand, he ignores the whole CSS statement so `&.is-#{$state}` (`&.is-warning`) won't be applied.

See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23371